# Could not find com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1

Tags: android, facebook, fresco

I'm trying to update the fresco library to the latest version (0.14.1) in the build.gradle file as per the instructions specified by the [official website](http://frescolib.org/docs/index.html).

[image]

It worked when I used earlier version but can't update to the new one.

Below is the error message.

> Error:Could not find com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.1.
>   Required by:
>       Coupon:app:unspecified
>   Search in build.gradle files

I've invalidated and cached the Android Studio. I've re-build and cleand the project number of times. It is of no use.

Comment: could you share your build.gradle (module project )?

Comment: Official version is compile 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:0.14.0'

Comment: @shuvro 0.14.0 worked. Where did you get that number?

Comment: Got it from github https://github.com/facebook/fresco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: 0.14.1 should now work.

Previous answer:
Please use 0.14.0 for now. 0.14.1 will be available shortly, we're still in the process of publishing the update.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, after banging my head for hours I realised that was caused by proguard configuration, I copied the most up to date rules from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/fresco/master/proguard-fresco.pro) and it dissappeared.